# Normal form of formula returned by Z3's qe tactic

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers

I'm using Z3's quantifier elimination tactic via Z3py and have tried the following examples.

```
from z3 import *
x,y,xp,yp = Ints('x y xp yp')
t = Tactic('qe')

t(Exists((xp, yp), And(xp==x+1, yp==y+2, xp<=8, xp >=1, yp<=12, yp>=2)))
#returns: [[y <= 10, y >= 0, x <= 7, x >= 0]]

t(Exists((xp, yp), Implies(x<10 , And(xp==x+1, yp==y+2, xp<=8, xp >=1, yp<=12, yp>=2))))
#returns: [[Or(10 <= x, And(y <= 10, y >= 0, And(x <= 7, x >= 0)))]]
```

I think that the resultant formulas are in quantifier-free DNF(which is what I need), but I could not find anything in the API documentation that guarantees it. Does anyone know if `qe` always returns formulas in DNF?

Where can I(if at all) find such details regarding tactics without having to dig through the original source code?

EDIT: All formulas are restricted to linear integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

By design, tactics make "best effort." That is, while `qe` is designed to eliminate quantifiers, it may end up failing to do so, returning the goal stack unchanged.

Note that quantifier elimination is not just one tactic, but it is a whole collection of them, depending on what other theories are involved in your benchmark. See the directory: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/src/qe

Comment: For my current use case, I have purely linear integer arithmetic formulas.
I tried reading the source you linked to, but I'm not at all familiar with Z3's internals. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I doubt there's any direct documentation other than the source code itself. If you're looking for general information on quantifier elimination, then I'm sure you can find many scholarly articles on that.